Piecewise Closed-Form for an Alternating Polynomial Sum in Terms of f(n)

Piecewise Closed-Form for an Alternating Polynomial Sum in Terms of  f(n) 

    I have a function 
    
$f(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} g(k)$
    where $g(k)$ is a polynomial of degree $m$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Now, I’m considering the alternating sum:


$S = \sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^{k} g(k)$


    I would like to derive a piecewise closed-form expression for $S$ in terms of $f(n)$, $g(k)$, and $n$ without involving summation notation. Specifically, I want the solution to handle the cases when $n$ is odd and when $n$ is even, and I want it to generalize for any polynomial $g(k)$.

What I’ve Tried:

Basic Summation: I’ve started with the known summation formulas, where $f(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} g(k)$, and for specific small polynomials like $g(k) = k$ or $g(k) = k^{2}$, I computed the alternating sum for small $n$ values.
However, I am struggling to generalize my approach to higher degrees and to avoid the summation notation.


What I’m Looking For:

A general closed-form expression for $S$ without summation notation that works for any polynomial $g(k)$.
A piecewise function that handles both odd and even values of $n$.


    I’ve heard that alternating sums of powers of integers involve Bernoulli numbers and might be related to Faulhaber’s formula, but I’m unsure how to apply these techniques to my problem.


    Any help or guidance on how to derive the expression or point me to relevant resources would be appreciated!


Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.
